# Adding UIButton and UITextField directly in UIWindow or adding in a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uibutton

I would like to understand a simple concept. I'm going to build a simple UI made up of a *UITableView*, an *UIButton* and *UITextField* objects. I add *UITableView* to *UIWindow*. Now I ask you which is the best way to add the others to object, wrapping into a *UIView* or inside an *UIWindow*. Which could be the advantages or disadvantages of both the approaches?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you will most likely want to use a `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController` which you then set as your window's `rootViewController`, and never actually add views to the window directly.

The other views you need should then be added to the view controller's managed `view`.

The main disadvantages of adding directly to window is that you do not get support for multiple interface orientations.

Comment: Yes sorry I have forgotten to mention the controllers. undoubtedly I use them to create the view. Always create application according MVC pattern

Comment: @Mazzy So did I answer your question or do you need some more guidance?